# How to change themes in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I followed instruction here but my documents do not change at all.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-apply-a-document-theme-in-word-2010.html

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this question without some more information. Can you hoover over the different themes or is themes grayed out? Can you change the style of a line manually to something else (fontsize, fontcolor etc.)? I take it is is a Word 2010 (`.docx`) document.

Answer (score 1):

I have found many examples to change themes in Word 2010. Here is a simple explanation:

> A theme in Microsoft Word 2010 consists of colours, fonts and effects.
>   Unlike individual styles that you can apply to each element (tables,
>   charts, etc), a theme affects all the content in your document.
>
> You can apply a theme with one click and the theme affects the style
>   of the whole document, providing a consistent look and feel across all
>   its elements. This means that the document’s tables and charts will
>   look good together.
>
> Source: [Microsoft Word 2010 – Themes](http://www.word-2010.com/microsoft-word-2010-themes)

You can changes these themes here:

[image]

> When you apply a theme to a Word 2010 document tables, charts,
>   SmartArt graphics, shapes, and other objects are updated to complement
>   one another.

Comment: Note: In other versions of Word, the ‘’Themes’’ button may be on the ‘’Design’’ tab.